# How can I detect borders of a piece of paper inside of an image and crop it using ImageMagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to crop paper documents from photographs.  For example, someone takes a picture of a document and sends it to the server and it will get edited to look like a scanned document.  How can I detect the border of the document and crop it using ImageMagick?

Thanks

Comment: -trim may work for you. http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the convert command with the [-trim option](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim) to crop out the solid color borders, and since the images are scanned, the [-fuzz option](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fuzz) to make sure trim completely crops the border even if the color isn't perfectly solid.

So something like this:

```
convert input.jpg -fuzz 2% -trim output.jpg
```

Translating that into PHP code, you'd end up with this:

```
$image = new Imagick('input.jpg');
$image->trimImage(2); // Trim the image with a 2% fuzz
$image->writeImage('output.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks, James.  This seems to be about what I need. Some of the pictures are going to have different sized borders, is there a way I can detect what % the fuzz should be?

Comment: The easiest way is just to experiment a bit with some typical examples of what your users are going to be uploading. Assuming the borders are a fairly solid color and the image contrast is good, then the fuzz setting shouldn't have to be too high.

Comment: Thanks for your help, James.  I was able to get something done with it by using Jcrop and the GD library. I just couldn't get it to detect the borders well enough.