# How remove white space in the JPG with PHP?

Tags: php, image, gd

I want crop white spaces and then resize image and save without those.
For example
http://stacktoheap.com/images/stackoverflow.png
This image can be cropped around 50 pixels from top and bottom.
Can I do it with PHP?

Comment: Do you already know where you need to crop?  Detecting what to crop, and then cropping it, are two different problems.

Comment: In mainly I want to know how detecting these white space, that then to crop it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063415/how-can-i-detect-borders-of-a-piece-of-paper-inside-of-an-image-and-crop-it-usin